# jupyter: how to stop execution on errors?

Tags: python, jupyter

The common way to defensively abort execution in python is to simply do something like:

```
if something_went_wrong:
    print("Error message: goodbye cruel world")
    exit(1)
```

However, this is not good practice when using **jupyter notebook**, as this seems to abort the kernel entirely, which is not always wanted. Is there are proper/better way in jupyter, besides hack-y infinite loops?

Comment: What version of jupyter? I tried and kernel didn't abort. However you can try `exit(keep_kernel=True)` instead

Comment: @Amit First of all: that seems to have worked, as the kernel does not stop now. However, I should clearify another anomaly: even when one expects the script to stop by the `exit` function immediately, it continues with the execution. When not setting the `keep_kernel=True` option, the kernel abortion is just deferred, but it stops eventually. What is really going on under the hood of jupyter?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No, `exit()` is **not** the way to abort Python execution usually.
`exit()` is meant to stop the interpreter immediately with a status code.

Usually, you will write a script like that:

```
 if __name__ == '__main__':
     sys.exit(main())
```

Try not to put `sys.exit()` in the middle of your code — it is bad practice, 
and you might end up with non closed filehandle or locked resources.

To do what you want, just raise an exception of the correct type. If it propagate to the eval loop, IPython will stop the notebook execution.

Also, it will give you useful error messages and a stack trace.

```
if type(age) is not int:
    raise TypeError("Age must be an integer")
elif age < 0:
    raise ValueError("Sorry you can't be born in the future")
else :
    ...
```

You can even inspect the stack post-mortem with `%debug` to see what went wrong where, but that is another subject.

Comment: This is was both an answer to my question and a general tip for improved code quality, all in one. Thank you!

Comment: Enjoy Python, and feel free to come contribute to IPython & Jupyter !

Comment: What if it is something for which a full stack trace is overkill? Often a simple one-line message to the user is much clearer if it is obvious what they did wrong.